# Copy file and display afterwards

Tags: linux, command

Can somebody give me an example how I can copy a file and open the copied file afterwards with the "cat" command in Linux? The statement should be in one line.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why has it to be in one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cheat:

`cat inputfile > outputfile && cat outputfile`

You can substitute the first part using cp:

`cp inputfile outputfile && cat outputfile`

You can use `;` instead of `&&`, so that the outputfile is displayed even if the copying did not succeed:

`cp inputfile outputfile; cat outputfile`

Or you can use `tee`:

`cat inputfile | tee outputfile` (note that this displays the file while copying, not afterwards)

Comment: Note that in your last command, the `tee` displays the file, not the `cat`, which is actually not needed: consider `tee outputfile < inputfile`.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean this?

```
cp file1 file2; cat file2
```

Comment: The problem here is that it will prompt if you do it again.

Comment: @sean: prompt? `cp` doesn't prompt unless you specifically ask it to. You probably have `alias cp cp -i` in your `.bashrc` or something.

Comment: If that's the case then don't use `yes` but it doesn't hurt if it's not set, but covers it just in case it is.